# Detectar quien gana en 3 en Raya con Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, binario

Estoy haciendo un validador de tablero de 3 en Raya, para determinar cual jugador a ganado la partida, he armado lo siguiente pero la función hasWon la he heredado por internet copy&paste y no acabo de comprender como funciona realmente

```kotlin
import java.time.Duration

val ROW_MAX = 3
val COL_MAX = 3

val winningPatterns: Array<Int> = arrayOf(
        0b111000000, 0b000111000, 0b000000111, // rows
        0b100100100, 0b010010010, 0b001001001, // columns
        0b100010001, 0b001010100)              // diagonals

//0 empty 1 cross 2 nought
val gameBoard = arrayOf(
    arrayOf(0, 1, 2),
    arrayOf(2, 1, 1),
    arrayOf(2, 1, 0)
)    
    
fun main() {
        
println("player 1 win? " + hasWon(1))
println("player 2 win? " + hasWon(2))


    
}


fun hasWon(thePlayer: Int): Boolean {
    var pattern = 0b000000000
    for (row in 0 until ROW_MAX) {
        (0 until COL_MAX)
                .asSequence()
                .filter {
                    gameBoard[row][it] == thePlayer }
                .forEach { pattern = pattern or (1 shl (row * COL_MAX + it)) }
    }

    winningPatterns
            .asSequence()
            .filter { (pattern and it) == it }
            .forEach { return true }

    return false
}
```

la parte que me gustaria comprender es la función `hasWon` en la parte que se hace el tratamiento de bit a bit y luego la comprobación con los patrones ganadores

Dejo código ejecutable en Kotlin Playgrounds, https://pl.kotl.in/oHAQnhrN1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el tablero en las casillas vacías hay un 1 en las casillas ocupadas por el jugador 1 hay un 1 y en las ocupadas por el jugador 2 hay un 2.

La función hasWon compara el valor del parámetro recibido con el contenido de las casillas.

Comienza poniendo un patrón a cero y después recorre cada casilla del tablero y si el valor de la casilla coincide con el del parámetro pone a 1 el elemento correspondiente del patrón.

La expresión: pattern = pattern or (1 shl (row * COL_MAX + it))
sirve para "poner a 1" en el patrón el bit correspondiente a la casilla que se está comprobando

Después compara el patrón con el array de vectores ganadores, si encuentra un ganador devuelve true, si recorre todo el array sin encontrar nada devuelve false.